# Windows 8 keeps same network info on each connection

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking

Recently got a new laptop, and it has Windows 8.1. I have a custom setup on my home network, with static IPs for each device connecting to the nework, and I use Google for my DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4). All of my other devices, whether that be a Win 7 laptop or smart phones, can connect to other wireless networks. Big reason is, the static IP and specific DNS settings for MY network only apply to MY network. They know to not use those settings when connecting to another network. Windows 8 doesn't seem to understand this, so I am having to reset my IPv4 settings whenever I travel with the new lappy. Is there a way around this, or is it something known in Win 8 problems?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are applying the settings to the profile rather than the adapter. This is the only reason I can think of why it is remembering the settings for all networks.

Comment: Do you mean profile as in the user, or profile as in the single network? If the latter, how do I make settings for just the one connection instead of the wireless adapter? Only way I know to set a static IP and DNS is `Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network Connections -> Wireless Adapter Properties -> IPv4 Properties`.

Answer (score 0):

One way around it is to handle all the static mappings (or at least the static mapping for this computer) in a DHCP server on your home network. You map the MAC address to the specific IP address, and hand out the DNS, NTP etc. you want things to use there.